# How to Resolve Incompatible Subnet Groups that AWS Generates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to create my first RDS Instance... I select `Create a new VPC` and then on the next page it tells me:

> "A VPC and DB Subnet Group are required but you do not have any compatible subnet groups for your current selection."

Why is it not recognizing the subnet group that is generated with the new vpc? I'm so confused.  How can I launch my database?

Answer (score 0):

From the RDS console, there is an option for "Subnet Groups" on the left.  You have to pick a VPC, then an existing subnet(s), before you can deploy RDS into it.